# Can't write in Firebase Realtime Database from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a simple Android App with Firebase.

At the moment I'm just trying to save users in real time Database from Firebase. But for some reason it doesn't work. On the other hand, the authentication works perfectly.

The Database itself doesnt show anything. It allways shows "null"

I've been following this YouTube tutorial and have been making things  pretty similar.

When i try to create one user and send it to the Database, I have no answer from the Running program. I have a progress bar that goes invisible as soon as the setValue(user) is completed. And that progressBar never goes invisible. Just stays there spinning.

Activity

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

private void registerUser() {
    String name = nameTV.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = emailTV.getText().toString().trim();
    String pwd = pwdTV.getText().toString().trim();
    String confirmPwd = confirmPwdTV.getText().toString().trim();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
            .addOnCompleteListener(ActivityRegister.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        User user = new User(email, name, pwd);

                        myRef.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "User has been registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityRegister.this, ActivityLogin.class));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "Failed to register. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "Failed to register. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Dependencies

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. That will also then enable syntax highlighting for Java and Kotlin automatically.

Comment: You never said you checked the firebase database, so I need to ask. Did you? Do you have anything in there written under users?

Comment: Do you get any Toast message?

Comment: No. The progress bar just keeps there spinning eternally. No Toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i finally managed to solve this.

Basically I had to download the google-services.json from the firebase page and replace with the json in my project.

I must have done something wrong when configuring the firebase for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code for the progressbar please?

Also you should be adding an OnCompleteListener to the setValue as well...this call is a Task so if you want to make sure it was a success, you should also attach a Listener to it.

Comment: Just Edited the original post with that